# {% for projects in profile.project_set.all %} is not displaying anything

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have been learning django through a video course and in the video course the guys has used

```
   {% for projectss in profile.project_set.all %}
       {{ projectss.title }}
   {% endfor %}
```

To display List of projects

Here is my **Model.py** file of project model

```
class Project(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Profile, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    id = models.UUIDField(default = uuid.uuid4 , primary_key=True, unique=True, 
    editable=False)
```

And Here is my **Model.py** of Users model

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, primary_key=True, editable=False, unique=True)
```

**View.py** file

```
def userProfile(request, pk):
    obj = Profile.objects.get(id=pk)
    context = {'user': obj}
    return render(request, 'users/user_profile.html', context)
```

The guy in video is doing the same thing its working for him but not me.

Comment: pay attention to the file extensions. You wrote twice `Model.js` but that code is written in Python. Is that a typo? check all your files extensions in the workspace, maybe that's the error

Comment: Where is the view that calls this template

Comment: @DelriusEuphoria At the bottom

Comment: @Seintian no no its model.py I accidently wrote .js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the context you are passing to the view:

```
context  = {'user': obj}
```

Change `'user'` to `'profile'` and you should be good.

```
def userProfile(request, pk):
    obj = Profile.objects.get(id=pk)
    context = {'profile': obj}
    return render(request, 'users/user_profile.html', context)
```